# Door jammed halfway round/around

Tags: word-usage

> The museum's revolving doors stopped the crooks as they jammed halfway _______.

Out of *round* and *around* which is the correct word  to use here ? I understand the literal meaning / difference between the two words but can't figure out which one to use in the above given phrase. Googling yields result showing both words being used interchangeably  (Actual phrase on google which I found was - Halfway round/around the world).

Comment: You should add your understanding of *round* and *around* and why you could not apply it to your example. Perhaps you are thinking of *'round* which is still *around*.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Googling". What English dictionary did you consult? (Google is not a dictionary.)

Comment: @user3169: No, "round", with much the same meaning as "around", is a [word in its own right](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/round).